# Palavras mais comuns entre rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Existe alguma função no MySQL que me de as 3 palavras mais comum entre uma coluna em formato `TEXT` de uma tabela?

Exemplo

```
Maria Joaquina
Maria Antonienta
Maria B.
```

entre esses *rows* ele retorna Maria por que ela foi um termo mais usado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro é preciso separar o delimitador para linhas, pode ser feito através de função ou uma solução encontrada no [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/4336024).

```
SELECT 
  dados.id, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dados.descricao, ' ', quantidade.n), ' ', -1) as descricao
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
     UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) as quantidade
INNER JOIN dados
     ON CHAR_LENGTH(dados.descricao)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(dados.descricao, ' ',''))>=quantidade.n-1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc93e2/10/0)

Após termos os dados linha por linha basta agrupar e ordenar pelo mais usado.

```
SELECT descricao, count(descricao) as quantidade
FROM ( ... )
GROUP BY descricao
ORDER BY quantidade DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc93e2/7/0)

Comment: Como posso colocar esse where `CONCAT(',',hash.tag,',') LIKE '%,tag,%'` no codigo? Tipo ir na tabela `table` WHERE `CONCAT(',',table.tag,',') LIKE '%,tag,%'` e executar seu codigo

Comment: Vc já respondeu sua duvida, apenas incluir a coluna `tag` no `FROM` e adicione o `WHERE`.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c28c09/1/0 @user3163662

Answer (score 7):

Uma forma é aproveitar o array e fazer a contagem dos itens repetidos usando [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-count-values.php). Você terá um output da seguinte forma:

```
Array
(
    [Maria] => 3
    [Joaquina] => 1
    [Antonienta] => 1
    [B] => 1
)
```

---

Trabalhei com uma string e usei explode, mas você pode adaptar ao resultado do mysql. Fiz um exemplo no [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/l9uoGf) para você ver.

```
$str = 'Maria Joaquina Maria Antonienta Maria B';
$str = explode( ' ' , $str );
$str = array_count_values( $str );
print_r( $str ); // retorna o output acima, com a contagem total
print_r( key( $str ) ); // retorna o primeiro índice com maior peso: `Maria`
```

Comment: Bom exemplo com `array_count_values` +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento. Precisei usar essa função a pouco tempo e lembrei dela agora. Economiza algumas linhas de loop.

Answer (score 5):

Não existe uma função pronta para fazer isto.

Eu sei que dá para fazer em SQL mas é mais complicado. Como minha familiaridade com SQL é mais limitada, especialmente do MySQL e como você colocou a *tag* [php](/questions/tagged/php) vou responder usado ele.

```
$resultado = mysqli_query("SELECT texto FROM tabela");
$contagem = array();
while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    $palavras = str_word_count($linha, 1);
    foreach($palavras AS $palavra) $contagem[$palavra]++;
}
arsort($contagem);
$i = 0;
foreach($contagem AS $key => $value) {
    echo $value . " => " . $key . "\n";
    $i++;
    if ($i >= 3) break;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/CountTopWords.php).

Answer (score 4):

Pode ser feito em php com `preg_split` (pode-se usar `explode` porém este só suporta um caractere por vez, e em caso de whitespaces o melhor é REGEX) e um vetor, no caso você pode preferencialmente criar uma função:

```
function buscarPalavraMaisRecorrente($data, $last=1) {
    $itens = array();
    
    $list = preg_split('/\s+/', strtolower($data));
    $j = count($list);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $j; ++$i) {
        $key = $list[$i];
        if (false === isset($itens[$key])) {
            $itens[$key] = 1;//Cria um item ex. maria
        } else {
            $itens[$key] += 1;//Soma
        }
    }

    $list = null;

    if (count($itens) === 0) {
        return array();
    }

    $j = max($itens);
    $j = max($j, $last);

    $found = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $j; ++$i) {
        $tmp = array_keys($itens, $j - $i);

        if (false !== $tmp) {
            $found = array_merge($found, $tmp);
        }
    }

    $found = array_slice($found, 0, $j);
    return $found;
}
```

Busca as 3 palavras mais usadas:

```
$exemplo = 'Maria Joaquina Maria Antonienta Maria B.';
print_r(buscarPalavraMaisRecorrente($exemplo, 3));
```

Retorna a palavra mais usada:

```
$exemplo = 'Maria Joaquina Maria Antonienta Maria B.';
print_r(buscarPalavraMaisRecorrente($exemplo));
```

Usando dentro do seu `while`:

```
while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo 'Palavra que mais repete: ',
          implode(',', buscarPalavraMaisRecorrente($linha['coluna_text'], 3));
}
```